# ANDROID GET CURRENT LOCATION IN A SERVICE

Tags: android, kotlin, gps, location

Hi I am using this function in a service to get my current location when I read something in the Bluetooth listener, but when the code run in foreground after few second the RequestLocationUpdate stop getting any result, and if I open the app it starts to run well again.
Someone know why? Thanks

```
private void getCurrentLocation() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);



        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
                .requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
                                .removeLocationUpdates(this);

                        if (locationResult != null && locationResult.getLocations().size() > 0) {
                            int latestlocationindex= locationResult.getLocations().size()-1;
                            lat=String.valueOf(locationResult.getLocations().get(latestlocationindex).getLatitude());
                            lon=String.valueOf(locationResult.getLocations().get(latestlocationindex).getLongitude());



                        }
                    }
                }, Looper.getMainLooper());

    }
```

Comment: You are essentially spinning up a service within your other service when you make a  `getCurrentLocation()` call based on your current code. You are not managing the state, but are questing stateful updates from the provider. Basically, you are screaming bits of location data into the ether, and not handling it.

I think the answer to your question is that you're removing location updates within the callback to your subscription to location updates, but I think you should reconsider this entire function.

Comment: Would be better create another service and check the location at intervals?

Comment: Or you know how can i get with a function the location without a loop?

Comment: _"RequestLocationUpdate stop getting any result"_ In your code you call `removeLocationUpdates()` to stop location updates.

Comment: @Duss I think it would be better to add a `state` object of some kind that you can tell it to "check again" or "stop checking", but otherwise it continuously polls at a safe (determined by the location api) rate. This might be called a "service" depending on what it does. Then you provide that state information as `LiveData` and you can _react_ to location changes or tell the app to stop checking entirely. Instead of running a loop, observe the live data and react.